# Different result in trigger and console (MYSQL 5.1.57)

Tags: mysql

I want to set 'isSomething' to 1 if the 'foo' is in column1 values, else 'isSomething' is 0

The problem is: the same query gives different result from console and from a trigger.
And the console version gives good result.

(everything is the same in the subquery, in the trigger I always get the same New.id! - test case)

```
-----TRIGGER (AFTER UPDATE)
...
DECLARE isSomething INT DEFAULT 0;

    select if('foo' IN (select column1 from ...where id=NEW.id),1,0)
    INTO isSomething;
...
LOG: isSomething:0

-----CONSOLE 
    select if('foo' IN (select column1 from ...where id=232),1,0)
into @isSomething;

select @isSomething;
...
CONSOLE: 1 (good result!!!)
```

COMMENT: i tried the following query as well

```
select count(*) into  isSomething from ... where id = NEW.id and column1='foo'
```

And it behaves like the first query.

**UPDATE 1**

Interesting the 2nd type of query without "and column1='foo'"

```
  select count(*) into  isSomething from ... where id = NEW.id
```

Gives right result:3, as if 'foo' wouldnt be in the result.

Comment: How are you logging the value of `isSomething`?

Comment: Observation: your trigger has the value of `NEW.column1` available to it. You don't need to fetch that value from the table.

Comment: @OllieJones: `column1` is probably from another table, or else definitely from another record (hence use of the `IN` operator, as multiple records are being returned by the subquery).

Comment: Stupid question, but is `NEW.id = 232`?  What happens if you run the subquery in the trigger with that constant value instead?

Comment: Q1.How are you logging the value of isSomething ?

A1.insert into debug.log set m=concat("isSomething:", isSomething);

A:Yes, the subquery can have more records (in my case it has 3 rows)

Comment: I tried to use the value of New.id directly, but isSomething is still 0

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

I dont know why, but if I use table alias (here:ft), then the query works and the result is good ...

```
    select count(*)
    into  isSomething
    from footable ft WHERE ft.column1 = 'foo' AND ft.id = NEW.id ....;
```

Thanks for everyone the effort!

Cs.